# Is it haram or halal to do research for bug bounty programs and is the prize money halal?

Tags: halal-haram, technology

There are many bug bounty programs like Microsoft, Google, ZDI etc. is it Halal to do personal research and look for bugs in bounty programs and is prize money halal ?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be halal?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a Muslim but logically it is allowed. You are not doing anything malicious, only acting upon an invitation by said company to find an eventual mistake made by their developers.

If you were to hunt for bugs without permission though, that would probably not be halal.